# Unknown type of C preprocessor macro

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Can anyone explain how the following C preprocessor macro works:

```
#define SQR(a) (sqrarg=(a),sqrarg*sqrarg)
```

The source code then uses it like so:

```
y = SQR(a - b);
```

Is this therefore the same as the following and if so why?

```
#define SQR(a) ((a)*(a))
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the idea behind the first form of `SQR` in your question is that if the argument to `SQR()` is a function, it only gets evaluated once.  That is, if you have:

```
#define SQR(a) ((a)*(a))
```

And you have in your code:

```
myval = SQR(myfunction())
```

This will evaluate to:

```
myval = (myfunction() * myfunction())
```

Whereas if you have:

```
#define SQR(a) (sqrarg=(a),sqrarg*sqrarg)
```

This evaluates to:

```
myval = (sqrarg=(myfunction()), sqrarg*sqrarg)
```

Which only calls `myfunction()` once.  If `myfunction()` is computationally intensive, this has just saved you a chunk of time.

Comment: Interesting - I never considered the fact that the macro argument could be a function rather than a variable... I'm accepting this answer as the point regarding saving time when evaluating `a`  is computationally expensive is something that I did not think about - Thanks larsks

Answer (score 3):

After expansion

```
y = (sqrarg=(a-b), sqrarg*sqrarg);
```

`,` is a comma operator therefore first `sqrarg=(a-b)` will be evaluated and `a-b` will be assigned to `sqrarg`, the value of expression `sqrarg=(a-b)` will be discarded. After that `sqrarg*sqrarg` will be evaluated and the result will be assigned to `y`.

> Is this therefore the same as the following and if so why?
>
> ```
>  #define SQR(a) ((a)*(a))
> ```

Yes. Except that in latter, `a` will be evaluated twice.

Comment: what is the scope of `sqrarg`?

Comment: scratch that. Doesn't this mean that `sqrarg` has to be already declared?

Comment: @bolov; Yes. It has to be defined.

Comment: Apologies I forgot to mention that `sqrarg` is listed as `static double sqrarg;` at the beginning of the source file.

Comment: Then you need to be careful, since the macro will do the same substitution for any type of parameter.   Not all numeric values survive a round trip to and from a double (for example large values of type long long).   If you only ever pass values of type double, probably better to write SQR() as a function, not a macro.